# How to interprete Tiff image spec 6.0 packbits compression

Tags: image, compression, tiff

The following is from TIFF 6.0 Specification Section 9: PackBits Compression

That is the essence of the algorithm. Here are some additional rules:

1. Pack each row separately. Do not compress across row boundaries.
2. The number of uncompressed bytes per row is defined to be (ImageWidth + 7)
   / 8. If the uncompressed bitmap is required to have an even number of bytes per
   row, decompress into word-aligned buffers.
3. If a run is larger than 128 bytes, encode the remainder of the run as one or more
   additional replicate runs

The first and the third items are easy to understand but I am confused about the second one specifically this: The number of uncompressed bytes per row is defined to be (ImageWidth + 7) / 8. Isn't that only true for 1 bit bi-level image. But to my knowledge, packbits is a byte oriented compression algorithm, it could be used for any type of tiff.

Could someone who knows about tiff and packbits give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TIFF document from this site: http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion-packbits.htm 
has the following at the top:

```
      Abstract

      This document  describes a  simple compression scheme for bilevel
      scanned and paint type files.


      Motivation

      The TIFF  specification defines  a number of compression schemes.
      Compression type  1 is  really no  compression, other  than basic
      pixel  packing.     Compression   type  2,   based  on  CCITT  1D
      compression,  is   powerful,  but   not  trivial   to  implement.
      Compression type  5 is  typically very effective for most bilevel
      images, as  well as  many deeper images such as palette color and
      grayscale images, but is also not trivial to implement.  PackBits
      is a simple but often effective alternative
```

So it is clear the additional rules are with respect to bilevel images. For some reason, the above abstract and description are missing from the pdf version of TIFF6.0.